# get data row in var

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, generics, collections

```
var a=from b in dc.Table1s select b;
int High=60,Low=50,c=0;    
foreach(var item in a)
{
   if(c>Low && c<High)
   {
      //do something
   }

   c++;
}
```

If you have 10,000 row of variable `a`.How can I get the contents of row 50 to 60 without changing the total `c` that can navigate

Comment: It is utterly useless to write `from x in y select x`

Comment: if you aren't using a anywhere else, you can also put c>Low / c<high as part of the query as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want `dc.Table1s.Skip(50).Take(10)`